# Get the object that invoke an event

Tags: python, events, wxpython

If I have two objects that will call the same methode then an event happens is it possible to see which of them that invoked the event?

To make it cleaer. If I have two buttons and one methode that are called then I click on them. What can I do in this methode to see whitch button that was clicked?

```
...
buttonA.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON ,self.methode)
buttonB.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON ,self.methode)
...
...
def methode(self,event)
  #get the button that was clicked
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
buttonA.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON ,self.methode)
buttonB.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON ,self.methode)
...
...
def methode(self, event)
  #get the button that was clicked 
  button = event.GetEventObject()

  print button.GetLabel()
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to create two separate methods:

```
buttonA.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.method_from_A)
buttonB.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.method_from_B)
```

If these two methods share code, then they could both call some other helper method.

Instead of naming them something arbitrary like method_from_X, try to pick names that would clarify why the cases are different. For names, focus on the "why" rather than on implementation details.

If you really want to have a single callback method, you can follow the instructions here on Passing Arguments to Callbacks:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/Passing%20Arguments%20to%20Callbacks

Comment: What if I got more than two objects (Buttons), let's say 100 then I would have to create 100 helper methodes. This will create a lot of meaningless code

Comment: You haven't given a lot of information about your use case. In general, having a one-to-one relationship between buttons and methods will make your code far more readable.

Could you give more information about what you're trying to do and why?